# Close the Postgre DB connection and open a new connection with different DB ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm migrating the previous database to my new application I have a dump file imported from heroku and there are some tables missing in the dump file as well in almost every table there are some attributes missing so for this I'm creating a new database and imported the dump in that database, and when I imported that from that DB and close the connection so that I can create a new connection with the production database where I need to migrate the data the connection is closed but the instance variables which I stored the data from the previous database is also reset so can anybody tell me how to close the Postgre DB connection and open a new connection to a different PG DB without loosing the saved data fetched from previous DB to populate the second DB.

I am using this to establish the connection

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('DB')
```

and I'm using to close the DB connection

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
```

Please answer my question?

Comment: I don't see a question here. Its more of an explanation of your problem. What is the problem, please be more specific.

Comment: Please read the question detail carefully.

Comment: can anybody tell me how to close the Postgre DB connection and open a new connection to a different PG DB without loosing the saved data fetched from previous DB to populate the second DB.

Comment: Please Edit the question and paste that comment as last line of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating setup for two databases in the database.yml
and added two methods for database connections one for one database connection using the

```
def xyz_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('DB')
end
```

and second for second DB connection like

```
def abc_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('DB')
end
```

and called them both where required and I did my insertions and DB manipulations and after that I suspended the connection from required DB.